# Android: Update sqlite db downloading file from webserver

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite database in my Android application, and I want to update it over the internet.
So I decided to use a webserver were I can store a txt file with sql statements. Then I'll download the file, and execute sql statements.
Now I have some questions:

- How I can protect the txt file? I don't want anyone to get access to my file using a normal browser.
- If I protect the file or the webserver, how I can authenticate to download it?
- Is this implementation the best way to update a local database over the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add authentication layer to your web server and when you need to access the file just send Authentication parameters with your request and you'll be able to access the file. Not sure if its the best implementation or not, depends on your application. How are you planning to update your database second time, is user going to request update on database?

Comment: Thanks, and how I can add authentication to my web? and then how I can send Authentication parameters?
I'm planning to update my database once at week. When the application starts I verify if there is an update over the server... and also user can request a manual update.

Comment: what kind of server are you using? Authentication credential's can be attached to `HTTP Request` and then be parsed at other end (your web server) and if it authenticates your server will respond by `HTTP Response` and attached will be your SQL file.

Comment: This is my server, i don't know how and what authentication I have to add... =(
http://translate.google.it/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.netsons.com%2Fhosting-condiviso.php&act=url

Comment: I see that your Host supports FTP accounts, just access your server using an FTP connection and read the file, use the following tutorial on opening FTP connections and reading files securely. https://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Comment: thanks, one more question... I have 400 users that use the application and have to update the database, does ftp allow simultaneos download?

Comment: reading a file simultaneously shouldn't be a problem, FTP will allow simultaneous download.